# Multiple IEnumerable iterations

Tags: c#, .net

I want to pass IEnumerable while having IEnumerable of IEnumerable.

Use case

```
class A
{
 IEnumerable<int> _ints;
 public A(IEnumerable<int> ints)  => _ints = ints;

 public B CreateB() => new B(_ints);
}

class B 
{ 
 public B(IEnumerable<int> ints)
 {
  foreach (int i in ints) { Console.WriteLine(i); }
 } 
}
    
class Program {
      static void Main() {
          var a = new A();
          a.CreateB(); // Sequence 1
          a.CreateB(); // Sequence 2
     }
}
```

There are 2 solutions.
1: Special IEnumerable which returns different sequence from GetEnumerator.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class MultiEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> _source;

        public MultiEnumerable(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
        {
            _source = source;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var current = _source.Take(1).First();
            _source = _source.Skip(1);
            return current.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public static class MultiEnumerableExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> AsMultiEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
        {
            return new MultiEnumerable<T>(source);
        }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> arrayOfArray =
                new[]
                {
                    new[] {1}, new[] {2}, new[] {3}, new[] {4}
                };

            IEnumerable<int> arrayOfArrayAsEnumerable = arrayOfArray.AsMultiEnumerable();

            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("---");
                foreach (var i in arrayOfArrayAsEnumerable)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Solution 2: Use method which takes IEnumerable of IEnumerable and returns first sequence while advancing:

```
 class Utils{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetFirstAndAdvance<T>(ref IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
  {
        var res = source.First();
        source = source.Skip(1);
        return res;
    }
 }

class A
{
 IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> _ints;
 public A(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> ints)  => _ints = ints;

 public B CreateB() => new B(Utils.GetFirstAndAdvance(ref _ints));
}
```

Comment: Don't you just want LINQ's `SelectMany` method? Or do you want to do this manually for some reason?

Comment: I want one level of IEnumerable and not nested.

Comment: @NN_ - Which is what `SelectMany` does.

Comment: 1) Just to confirm, you really want an `IEnumerable<T>` that enumerates a difference sequence each time it is enumerated, correct?  2) You wrote, *Is there any issue with this implementation ?* -- what is your question here?  Is the code working correctly?  If not, can you provide a [mcve]?  If your code works correctly and you want a general critique, this might be more appropriate for [codereview.se].

Comment: Oh, thanx ! There are so many projects in stackexchange, I didn't know there is such project. Yeah, I guess it suits there better.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of issues with your implementation of `MultiEnumerable<T>`.

To start with, these two lines are causing multiple iterations of the outer enumerable:

```
var current = _source.Take(1).First();
_source = _source.Skip(1);
```

Each time you go back and call `GetEnumerator()` you're running through the outer enumerable again to get back to the next inner enumerable.

Next, you're expecting the caller to know how many times to call `GetEnumerator()`. You've done this in your code with the `for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)` where you know you should iterate the code `4` times. Had you iterated 5 times you would have gotten a n `InvalidOperationException` exception telling you that the "Sequence contains no elements".

These problems would have gone away had you written your test code using standard C# `foreach` loops.

```
foreach (var array in arrayOfArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine("---");
    foreach (var i in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Which really then leads to a way of writing a better `MultiEnumerable<T>`

```
internal class MultiEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> _source;

    public MultiEnumerable(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<T> Iterate()
    {
        foreach (var inner in _source)
        {
            foreach (var element in inner)
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => this.Iterate().GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Or even more simply, ignore the helper class, and just implement like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsMultiEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    foreach (var inner in source)
    {
        foreach (var element in inner)
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Naturally, your test code becomes simpler in both implementations:

```
IEnumerable<int> arrayOfArrayAsEnumerable = arrayOfArray.AsMultiEnumerable();

foreach (var i in arrayOfArrayAsEnumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

However, this code now just re-implements `SelectMany`. You could have just written your code like this:

```
foreach (var i in arrayOfArray.SelectMany(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

It's better to use a well-known, standard operator as the code should then be easier to read and reason about.

Comment: This is exactly what I want each GetEnumerator retuns next sequence. I do not want IEnumerable to return all elements in all sequences.

Comment: @NN_ - It's seriously abusing the interface. What's the use-case?

Comment: I do not think it is a serious abuse. Think about Concurrent collections are allowed to return totally different sequence each time you enumerate them. I have a class receiving IEnumerable and the other option is to make it receive IEnumerable<IEnumerable> and then I need some method to get first sequence and advance to next. Now I am thinking what is the simplest here, do this trick in one place or change code in many others.

Comment: @NN_ - It's an abuse because you never know when to stop asking for enumerations of your `MultiEnumerable<T>` instance. You'd have to iterate the outer enumerable to find out how many you should iterate, but in doing that you're performing even more iterations.

Comment: @NN_ - What's the actual use-case?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I updated the question with 2 proposed solutions. I In the end seems like second will be more obvious for other developers. WDYT ?

Comment: @NN_ - The use-case you put in the question makes no sense to me. It doesn't compile to start with. If I assume you meant to passing an `IEnumerable<int>` to the constructor of `A` then the code just writes the contents of that enumerable when you call `CreateB`. It doesn't appear to pertain to your original question.

Comment: Forgot to update. It should receive IEnumeraboe of IEnumerable of course.

Comment: @NN_ - Your use-case has made things confusing. Please fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use LINQ's `SelectMany` method.

```cs
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> arrayOfArray = new[]
 {
     new[] {1}, new[] {2}, new[] {3}, new[] {4}
 };

var allElements = arrayOfArray.SelectMany(element => element);

foreach (var element in allElements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}

// Output:
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

Comment: I do not want such behavior.